# Struggling to dispatch GAP_INIT command correctly (HCI commands with payloads)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have an ST Micro Bluetooth 4.1 Bluenrg chip communicating connected to an xmega256a3u via SPI.  I can communicate with the chip and send simple commands (e.g. `HCI_READ_LOCAL_VERSION_INFORMATION` (0x1001)).

My problem comes when I try to send an ACI command with a payload (e.g. `GAP_INIT` (0xFC8A)).

```
MOSI 0x0A  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x01  0x8A  0xFC  0x01  0x01
MISO 0x02  0x7F  0x00  0x00  0x00  0xFF  0xFF  0xFF  0xFF  0xFF
```

Then read:

```
MOSI 0x0B  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00
MISO 0x02  0x7F  0x00  0x0C  0x00  0x04  0x0E  0x0A  0x01  0x8A  0xFC  0x12  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x00
```

The status response `0x12` (12th byte in `MISO`) tells me that I have something wrong with my payload length, payload structure, or command packet. Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *BlueNRG-MS* and newer firmware for the *Bluenrg* change the `GAP_INIT` command from *1 byte* to *3 bytes*:

> **Role (1 byte):**
>   0x01:Peripheral 0x02: Broadcaster 0x04: Central 0x08: Observer
>
> **Privacy (1 byte):**
>   0x00: Privacy is disabled 0x01: Privacy is enabled
>
> **Length of Device Name (1 byte):**
>   Length of the device name characteristic